# Industrial Oven Control

Tags: control-system, plc, best-practice

I'm working on upgrading an ancient oven that we bought second hand, which came with almost zero documentation.
I have identified two fans one is exhaust fan and the other is a circulation fan.
Is it common practice for the circulation fan and the exhaust fan both run continuously, or should I treat the exhaust as a "cooling" loop when designing the control system?

Comment: If it is an electric oven, I would treat the exhaust fan as a cooling element. If it is a fuel fed oven, I would worry that the exhaust fan might be intended to remove carbon dioxide, so that carbon _monoxide_ doesn't form, in which case it might be intended to run continuously.

Comment: Yes it is an electric oven.

Comment: Then treat the exhaust fan as a mechanism for cooling the oven if/when you want to do that. Leave the circulation fan running to maintain an even temperature.

Comment: what exactly does the exhaust fan do? ... what is the path of the air? ... it is possible that it does not impact the oven chamber

Comment: Is the oven for something that off-gases when heated and requires the fumes to be safely extracted?

Comment: The oven will be curing carbon fiber and epoxy parts. The oven is well sealed and there's no apparent path for fresh air to fill the oven. I imagine the exhaust might pull a slight vacuum when it's on.

Comment: If you're curing things in there, you might want to hook up the exhaust fan so that it turns on when the door is open and sends the exhaust somewhere responsible.  Some of those epoxy hardeners are relatively safe at room temp but anything that increases the amount of vapor from e.g. any unmixed dribbles could generate a dangerous amount of fumes.  We use 834HTC which is safe when cured but a nightmare beforehand.

Comment: turn on the exhaust fan and test the measure the air flow at the outlet using a smoke source or a streamer, there may be inlets in unexpected locations.

Comment: You should consult the epoxy manufacturer for details on what to do with the extracted fumes: it might be sufficient to ventilate them to outside, or a carbon filter might be a good idea, or maybe the fumes need to be scrubbed.